# MSSQL CREATE INDEX WANT create an UNIQUE index

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem:

```
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_table_column] ON [dbo].[table1] 
(
    [column1] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

When I perform this script on SQL Server 10.50.2500, there is no problem

but when I want perfom it on SQL Server 10.50.4000 I get the error that the **unique** index can't be created( double and null values)

Why wants the 4000 create an unique index?

The column datatype is uniqueindentifier, no constraints not fk, same DB on both servers.

Comment: Thx, can you give maybe more infos?

Comment: The columndatatype is uniqueidentifier.

Comment: If the error message says you are creating an UNIQUE index, then it must be that you are requesting an UNIQUE index. You are **not** running the command you think you're running. Post the exact sequence of actions you're doing.

Comment: Copy in management studion and press F5 thats all I do

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaken, you must have different data or a different schema on the instances you are comparing.

This functionality is not altered between those server versions.

I suspect that the failing table has multiple `NULL` values in `[column1]`.

---

If you can show a script that creates the table, inserts some data and applies the index and, isn't obviously wrong then ...

Comment: Ok it is not the server, I just restored a new backup on the 2500 and get the same error now(the first backup I tested was from yesterday)

Comment: But why it wants create an unique index?

Comment: @user1082070, it must be specified in what you are executing.

Comment: OK thanks for the ideas Problem is found:

Comment: OK the problems were double values in the pk column(columnPK)(no idea how this can happen).

The workaround was to drop the pk, fix the double values, the can't be found while the pk exists and recreate it again. 

After that i could create my index on column1.

The confusing was the error message:
THE CREATE UNIQue index statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name...